# Is there a particular reason that using clone = obj *1 is avoided when "cloning" objects?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, clone

In [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612990/4569807) it is shown that slicing is faster than anything in terms of making a copy of an item.

Using:

```
list1 = ['foo','bar']
copy1 = list1 * 1
list1.pop()
print 'list1: ' + list1
print 'copy1: ' + copy1
```

I get:

```
list1: ['foo']
copy1: ['foo', 'bar']
```

Any particular reason to stay away from making copies like this?

Comment: Why not `copy1 = list(list1)`?

Comment: None I can think of, except readability. As suggested ^^^^ `list(x)` is the optimal way. Also, as you can see, `x * n` is quite easy to confuse with `[x] * n` (which is entirely different ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget you're duplicating a reference to the **same** object, which is not what you (usually) expect:

If you mean to create a `list` of 3 lists of '1':

```
>>> lst = [[1]] * 3
>>> lst
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

Now do something to the first one item:

```
>>> lst[0].append(2)
```

Oops, it's the same object in all three locations:

```
>>> lst
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

I'd expect `[[1, 2], [1], [1]]`, but that's subjective I guess, that's why I wouldn't use it. At least not with mutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

*slicing is faster than anything in terms of making a copy of an item.*

You can easily test this yourself:

```
timeit.timeit('clone = lst * 1', 'lst = ["foo", "bar"]', number=10000000)
```

For me, I get a time of `0.8731180049981049`

The same test with a slice instead:

```
timeit.timeit('clone = lst [:]', 'lst = ["foo", "bar"]', number=10000000)
```

Gives a time of: `0.9454964299984567`

So the `*` operator seems to actually be faster.  As to why people use `[:]` instead? It's more obvious as to what its doing.

---

This breaks down when copying lists of lists, consider:

```
>>> lst = [[1], [2]]
```

Copying with a slice and with a `*1` still allows for modification of the original list

```
>>> copy1 = lst[:]
>>> copy1[0].append('x')
>>> lst # is affected by the above
[[1, 'x'], [2]]

>>> copy2 = lst * 1
>>> copy2[0].append('y')
>>> lst # is also affected by the above
[[1, 'x', 'y'], [2]]
```

But with a list comprehension the sequence can be deep-copied

```
>>> copy3 = [l[:] for l in lst]
>>> copy3[0].append('z')
>>> lst # unaffected
[[1, 'x', 'y'], [2]]

>>> copy4 = [l * 1 for l in lst]
>>> copy4[0].append('z')
>>> lst # also unaffected
[[1, 'x', 'y'], [2]]
```

Comment: Ahh I see, didn't know that a list of lists would work a little differently.